# AES_encrypt : initialization of one of the variables

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this function that in the first call, is giving me back the Correct Encrypted Value

```
120692dbcdca656394fc10147e2418f2
```

But all that comes after are incorrect :

```
764e1a39b43c42f30da2e9e327d4ed22
b93b46dbc936ae3b06f571ffe1a59cac
b93b46dbc936ae3b06f571ffe1a59cac
a71787b35326e282f8c1bf3a0a034620
```

I'm new with C++ and I think it is a matter of initialization of one of the variables.
I did many Tests but I'm not able to point out where is the Error.
Could someone help me please ?
Thank You -

```
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


char* pxEnAndDeCrypt(char* pStr )
{
    
    static const unsigned char key[] = {0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55};
    char *ptr = NULL;

    unsigned char enc_out[80]= {};
    unsigned char dec_out[80]= {};
    
    int i,j,lenHexa ;
    char enc_out_HEXA[200]= {};
    unsigned char enc_out_TRANSF[200]= {};
    unsigned char enc_out_BACK[200]= {};

    AES_KEY enc_key, dec_key;

        // ENCRYPT :                              Input =*pStr             Output = enc_out

        AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &enc_key);
        AES_encrypt((const unsigned char *)pStr, enc_out, &enc_key);  

        // TRANSFORM OUTPUT OF ENCRYPT TO HEXA :  Input =enc_out           Output = enc_out_HEXA

        int len  = strlen((char*)enc_out);

        for (i = 0, j = 0; i < len; ++i, j += 2)
        { 
              sprintf(enc_out_HEXA  + j, "%02x", enc_out[i] & 0xff);
        }
        ptr = (char *) enc_out_HEXA;

// OUTPUT 

    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: You are telling `AES_set_encrypt_key` that you are passing in 128 bits of key and then only pass in 6 bytes (=48 bits). That doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Yes, sorry I cut it just for here :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that your function returns a pointer to `enc_out_HEXA`.

```
ptr = (char *) enc_out_HEXA;
return ptr;
```

The issue here is that `enc_out_HEXA` is declared inside `pxEnAndDeCrypt` so it no longer exists once you have exitted `pxEnAndDeCrypt`, so your function is returning a pointer to an object which no longer exists. This results in the strange behaviour you see.

Since you are programming C++, the simple solution is to use C++ (your current code is pure C). Instead of returning a pointer, return a `std::string`.

```
#include <string>

std::string pxEnAndDeCrypt(char* pStr )
{
    ...
    return ptr;
}
```

There are many other places in the above code where you could replace the C code with C++. But this simple change should be enough to get over the current problem.

Of course you will also have to change the code that calls `pxEnAndDeCrypt`, but since you didn't post that I can't really help with that.

**EDIT**

Here's an alternative solution that doesn't require `std::string`.

The basic problem is that `enc_out_HEXA` has been declared inside the `pxEnAndDeCrypt` function and so you can't use it (or a pointer to it) outside the function. So one solution is to move the `enc_out_HEXA` to the calling function and pass a pointer to that array to the function. Like this

```
void pxEnAndDeCrypt(char* pStr, char* result)
{
    ...
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < len; ++i, j += 2)
    { 
          sprintf(result + j, "%02x", enc_out[i] & 0xff);
    }
}
```

Then somewhere else in your code you will have

```
char enc_out_HEXA[200];
pxEnAndDeCrypt(some_string, enc_out_HEXA);
```

That's the solution that would be used in a C program.

Comment: hello, This function is called inside an ETL program ( in Datastage ). Then I can just choose to create the function like :   char*   , char , unsigned char ,  then other numeric types. But what I see anyways is the first time I call the function through my ETL program, it works ok, then the problems comes after that,  from the 2d call and so on.

Comment: @Gius Well I don't know anything about the things you are talking about. But I've editted the question above to include a solution that doesn't require use of C++ features like `std::string`. You should probably also pay attention to the comment that Mike Vine made above. C and C++ are complex languages, it's hard to write even the simplest piece of code if you don't know them.

Comment: thank you John , yes you are completely right,  it is very complex and I'm still fighting to understand :)